# gradient color in bar ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to put the same gradient colours as the legend, but in the bars, not in numbers. How I do it?

```
ggplot(francia, aes(x = reorder(Equipo, Gls.), y = Gls., colour = Gls.)) +
    geom_col( aes()) + 
    labs(title = "Goles por equipo", x="Equipos", y= "Goles") +
    geom_text(aes(label = Gls.), nudge_y = 2) + 
    coord_flip() +
    scale_colour_gradient(name = 'Goles', 
                          low = "Black", high = "green") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"), strip.background = element_rect(fill="francia"))
```

[image: This is my plot]

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is switch the `color` aesthetic to the `fill` aesthetic.

```
ggplot(francia, aes(x = reorder(Equipo, Gls.), y = Gls., fill = Gls.)) +
    geom_col( aes()) + 
    labs(title = "Goles por equipo", x="Equipos", y= "Goles") +
    geom_text(aes(label = Gls.), nudge_y = 2) + 
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_gradient(name = 'Goles', 
                          low = "Black", high = "green") +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "grey"), strip.background = element_rect(fill="francia"))
```